# Python code with ChatGPT, Telegram, and Google Text-to-Speech: How to fix audio file not returning in chat?

Tags: python, telegram, google-text-to-speech

Hello:) I have a python code to connect ChatGPT to telegram bot and it works fine. I added some code to have a text to speech function. However, it does not return a audiofile in the telegram chat (and I do not see an error in Visual Studion. Do you know what the error is?

I marked the parts for the voice to text in bold. Thank you very much for any help in advance:)

```
# 1. Start by importing the necessary libraries and setting up the API clients 
import requests
import json
import os
import threading

# integrate Google Text-to-Speech (TTS)
from gtts import gTTS

# OpenAI secret Key
API_KEY = 'MY API KEY'
# Models: text-davinci-003,text-curie-001,text-babbage-001,text-ada-001
MODEL = 'gpt-3.5-turbo'
# Telegram secret access bot token
BOT_TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN'
# Defining the bot's personality using adjectives
BOT_PERSONALITY = 'Answer in a friendly tone, '
# Specify your Chat Bot handle
CHATBOT_HANDLE = '@ask_chatgptbot'

#create a function to convert text to speech
**def text_to_speech(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')  # you can change the language
    filename = 'voice.mp3'
    tts.save(filename)
    return filename**

# 2a. Function that gets the response from OpenAI's chatbot
def openAI(prompt):
    # Make the request to the OpenAI API
    response = requests.post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
        headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {API_KEY}'},
        json={'model': MODEL, 'messages': [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}], 'temperature': 0.5, 'max_tokens': 300},
        timeout=10
    )

    result=response.json()
    
    final_result=''
    for i in range(0,len(result['choices'])):
        final_result+=result['choices'][i]['message']['content']

    return final_result

# 2b. Function that gets an Image from OpenAI
def openAImage(prompt):
    # Make the request to the OpenAI API
    resp = requests.post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations',
        headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {API_KEY}'},
        json={'prompt': prompt,'n' : 1, 'size': '1024x1024'},
        timeout=10
    )
    response_text = json.loads(resp.text)
      
    return response_text['data'][0]['url']

**# send audio file to chat
def telegram_bot_send_audio(audio_file, chat_id, msg_id):
    data = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
        'reply_to_message_id': msg_id,
        'audio': open(audio_file, 'rb')
    }
    url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + BOT_TOKEN + '/sendAudio'
    
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, timeout=10)
    
    return response.json()**

# 3a. Function that sends a message to a specific telegram group
def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message,chat_id,msg_id):
    data = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
        'text': bot_message,
        'reply_to_message_id': msg_id
    }
    response = requests.post(
        'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + BOT_TOKEN + '/sendMessage',
        json=data,
        timeout=10
    )
    return response.json()

# 3b. Function that sends an image to a specific telegram group
def telegram_bot_sendimage(image_url, group_id, msg_id):
    data = {
        'chat_id': group_id, 
        'photo': image_url,
        'reply_to_message_id': msg_id
    }
    url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + BOT_TOKEN + '/sendPhoto'
    
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, timeout=5)
    return response.json()
  
# 4. Function that retrieves the latest requests from users in a Telegram group, 
# generates a response using OpenAI, and sends the response back to the group.
def Chatbot():
    # Retrieve last ID message from text file for ChatGPT update
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    filename = cwd + '/chatgpt.txt'
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            f.write("1")
    else:
        does_file_exist="File Exists"    

    with open(filename) as f:
        last_update = f.read()
    f.close()
        
    # Check for new messages in Telegram group
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/getUpdates?offset={last_update}'
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    data = json.loads(response.content)
    print(data)   
    
    for result in data['result']:
        try:
            # Checking for new message
            if float(result['update_id']) > float(last_update):
                # Checking for new messages that did not come from chatGPT
                if not result['message']['from']['is_bot']:
                    last_update = str(int(result['update_id']))
                    
                    # Retrieving message ID of the sender of the request
                    msg_id = str(int(result['message']['message_id']))
                    
                    # Retrieving the chat ID 
                    chat_id = str(result['message']['chat']['id'])
                    

                  **  # Checking if user wants a voice message
                    if result['message']['text'].startswith("/textspeech"):
                        prompt = result['message']['text'].replace("/textspeech", "").strip()
                        bot_response = openAI(f"{BOT_PERSONALITY}{prompt}")
                        speech_file = text_to_speech(bot_response)
                        telegram_bot_send_audio(speech_file, chat_id, msg_id)**
                    # Checking if user wants an image
                    if '/img' in result['message']['text']:
                        prompt = result['message']['text'].replace("/img", "")
                        bot_response = openAImage(prompt)
                        print(telegram_bot_sendimage(bot_response, chat_id, msg_id))
                    # Checking that user mentionned chatbot's username in message
                    if CHATBOT_HANDLE in result['message']['text'] or "superdan" in result['message']['text'] or "Superdan" in result['message']['text']:
                        prompt = result['message']['text'].replace(CHATBOT_HANDLE, "")
                        # Calling OpenAI API using the bot's personality
                        bot_response = openAI(f"{BOT_PERSONALITY}{prompt}")
                        # Sending back response to telegram group
                        print(telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_response, chat_id, msg_id))
                    # Verifying that the user is responding to the ChatGPT bot
                    if 'reply_to_message' in result['message']:
                        if result['message']['reply_to_message']['from']['username'] == CHATBOT_HANDLE[1:]:
                            prompt = result['message']['text']
                            bot_response = openAI(f"{BOT_PERSONALITY}{prompt}")
                            print(telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_response, chat_id, msg_id))
        except Exception as e: 
            print(e)

    # Updating file with last update ID
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(last_update)
    f.close()
    
    return "done"

# 5 Running a check every 5 seconds to check for new messages
def main():
    timertime=5
    Chatbot()   
    # 5 sec timer
    threading.Timer(timertime, main).start()

# Run the main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have a python code to connect ChatGPT to telegram bot and it works fine. I added some code to have a text to speech function. However, it does not return a audiofile in the telegram chat (and I do not see an error in Visual Studion.

Comment: you should reduce the code and the problem to `get text to speech function working`: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example